# AWS RDS backups and restore

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have some questions regarding AWS backups on their RDS.
I have a mysql server with 2 schemas which needs backing up from unintentional messing with entries in tables. As far I understand Snapshots and restoring DB to specified time would restore the entire DB values to that time and basically we need to change a specific entry without restoring the rest. Is that possible? So far we would copy entire row of data from the table before altering entries just in case it values needed to be restored.